# DOJO : Not able to initialize the js Using New Keyword

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, dojo

I have a link, if i click the link i need to call another Js using new keyword like below.

```
<a style="padding: 2px 15px" data-dojo-attach-event="click:display">Form</a>

display : function(){
new com.cn.clb.dr.mytasks.BrandForm({
            formInfo: brandForm,
            brand: brandName
        }, formPlacer).initialize();
}
```

Here very first time(1st time page loading) above js called perfectly, After that, i was clicked the link the above js is not called.

In the JS i have included both postcreate() and initialize().

Please tell me how to call the js.

Comment: Are you sure it's entirely not called, and not just that there's an error that occurs?  Check the console in dev tools and try logging before/after `new ...`.  I suspect that perhaps the `formPlacer` reference isn't valid the second time through, but with only this code to go on, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: this is called when the page is loading very first time, in the same page i have link, if i click the link again i call the method that time the BrandForm is not executed. there is no error coming in the dev tool.

Comment: i put a log before and after new ... but before and after log is printing when the page is loading very first time, after that before log alone only printing.

Note : If i reload the page it is working.

Comment: That would probably indicate that the `new ...` statement is throwing an error. :)  Try turning on "break on all errors" in the dev tools, or putting a try/catch around it and logging the error in the catch block to see what's actually happening.

Comment: Ken, i got below error 

Error: Tried to register widget with id==supportDoc_1 but that id is already registered

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information that Dijit is telling you you're trying to register a widget with an ID that's already registered, you need to destroy the first widget you create before creating another one based on the same element.

Additionally, the second argument passed to widget constructors indicates `srcNodeRef`, which is a node that will be *replaced* with the widget's own DOM.  I'm sort of guessing here since there's not much context, but you probably don't want to be passing the same node reference to it multiple times since it will probably be invalid after the first.

Here is an example of something I would expect to work better, which destroys the widget if it exists from a previous call using `destroyRecursive`, and uses `placeAt` to place the widget under a parent node rather than using the `srcNodeRef` argument to replace a node.

```
display : function(){
    var parentNode;
    if (this._displayWidget) {
        parentNode = this._displayWidget.domNode.parentNode;
        this._displayWidget.destroyRecursive();
    }
    else {
        parentNode = formPlacer.parentNode;
    }
    this._displayWidget = new com.cn.clb.dr.mytasks.BrandForm({
        formInfo: brandForm,
        brand: brandName
    }).placeAt(parentNode).initialize();
}
```

Note that this currently doesn't take into account position among siblings in the parent node; it should be possible to amend the `placeAt` call accordingly.

Comment: Finally i got the fix, we are using ID attribute in html file, so instead of using ID am using data-dojo-attach-point in the html.

After this change its working fine now.

Thanks Ken for your support

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the fix, we are using ID attribute in html file, so instead of using ID am using data-dojo-attach-point in the html. After this change its working fine now.

instead of using id am using data-dojo-attach-point.